# pymongo ServerSelectionTimeoutError with a valid mongo URL

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

I've been having issues while connecting to a MongoDB database using pymongo.

I use valid URLs, since my colleagues are using the same and it works fine for them, but I keep getting ServerSelectionTimeoutError.

The databases are hosted on MongoAtlas, do you have any idea about what the issue is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any issue with a ServerSelectionTimeoutError is a connection issue with the targeted database.

It turns out MongoAtlas has a nice documentation about those: https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/troubleshoot-connection/

In my case, the issue was that I was on a network with a firewall that closed the needed 27017 port, a simple change of network did the trick.